# Stripe Apple pay integration is not working in iOS (Swift) application

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I am working on Stripe payment integration and I am using 'Standard' integration to implement Stripe in iOS (Swift). For this I am referring this document "https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios" and demo code : "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios"  and I am referring 'Standard' integration demo.

I have successfully implement Credit card payment in app and its working perfectly for both sandbox and live.

Now I have to integrate Apple pay using Stripe. But I am not able to do that.

These are the code which I am using:

**CheckoutViewController.swift**

```
@objc func didTapApplePay() {

        self.paymentInProgressApplePay = true


        let merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.companyName.appName"
        let paymentRequest = Stripe.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: merchantIdentifier, country: "US", currency: "USD")

        // Configure the line items on the payment request
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Fancy Hat", amount: 50.00),
            // The final line should represent your company;
            // it'll be prepended with the word "Pay" (i.e. "Pay iHats, Inc $50")
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "iHats, Inc", amount: 50.00),
        ]

        if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(paymentRequest) {
            // Setup payment authorization view controller
            let paymentAuthorizationViewController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)

            paymentAuthorizationViewController?.delegate = self as! PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate

            // Present payment authorization view controller
            present(paymentAuthorizationViewController!, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            // There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration

    print("There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration")

        }

    // self.paymentContext.requestPayment()

    }
```

In above code I am getting response in console is *"There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration"*

Following things I have done in my application:

1. I have created certificate from the stripe dashboard and upload it my stripe dashboard. Also install this certificate in my keychain access:

[image]

2. Set on Apple pay in Xcode capabilities:

[image]

```
if Stripe.deviceSupportsApplePay(){


            print("Device support apple pay")

        }
        else{

            print("Device does not support apple pay")


        }
```

In above code I am getting response in console is "*Device does not support apple pay*"

I am really not able to figure it out that what exact problem is? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of device are you testing on? Unfortunately I don't think some of the simulators in XCode don't support Apple Pay, so the best way to test is to deploy to a real device and use your real Apple Pay wallet(no charge will be taken when using test mode Stripe keys).

Comment: @karllekko I am running my application on iPhone 7.

Comment: If you want to check in simulator then check in ios 12 os simulator then it will work also if you are using real device then you need to save your card detail or need to save payment method in device settings. Then it will work.